# How to design shape for Android TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-cardview

I am designing a chat application . I have to design chat `UI` like below image .

I can design the whole `UI` with `Cardview` , but the thing which I am stuck is that rounded shape `TextView`(Background color - green) .

How can I get that Shape for `TextView` ?

[image: Chat UI]

Comment: show the layout you have tried so far

Comment: You can try create a shape and assign that as a background of a textview.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, just look at Android 9 patch drawables:
[official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

And you should create "bubble.9.png" file similar to what I've done:
[bubble.9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkBqo.png)

And then you should set this image as TextView background